# How to convert Search Keywords in search texarea into a forward link?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, search, textarea

I have small script that planned to function like that:
When someone search for product and click on the white arrow, it will forward him to ebay with the keywords as an ebay product search results.

I want that when someone search lets say: samsung galaxy s5, the script will generate the kewords and forward it to the correct address. And ill explain:

For example:

Im searching for **samsung galaxy s5** so the Full link address is:

> http://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-53200-19255-0/1?icep_ff3=9&pub=5575165347&toolid=10001&campid=5337851510&customid=&icep_uq=samsung+galaxy+s5&icep_sellerId=&icep_ex_kw=&icep_sortBy=12&icep_catId=&icep_minPrice=&icep_maxPrice=&ipn=psmain&icep_vectorid=229466&kwid=902099&mtid=824&kw=lg

As a result it should forward me to address that look like that:

> http://www.ebay.com/sch/items/?_nkw=samsung+galaxy+s5&_sacat=&_ex_kw=&_mPrRngCbx=1&_udlo=&_udhi=&_sop=12&_fpos=&_fspt=1&_sadis=&LH_CAds=&rmvSB=true

But, with my current script all i get is that (below) address as a result:

> http://www.ebay.com/?q=samsung+galaxy+s5&rmvSB=true

I try to put **% after**:

> http://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-53200-19255-0/1?icep_ff3=9&pub=5575165347&toolid=10001&campid=5337851510&customid=&icep_uq=

and **before**:

> &icep_sellerId=&icep_ex_kw=&icep_sortBy=12&icep_catId=&icep_minPrice=&icep_maxPrice=&ipn=psmain&icep_vectorid=229466&kwid=902099&mtid=824&kw=lg

But i get the same address result as:

> http://www.ebay.com/?q=samsung+galaxy+s5&rmvSB=true

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Box Example 2 - default placeholder text gets cleared on click</title>
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
<!-- Add jQuery to your website if you don't have it already -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<!-- JAVASCRIPT to clear search text when the field is clicked -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#tfq2b").click(function() {
        if ($("#tfq2b").val() == "Search our website"){
            $("#tfq2b").val(""); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
<!-- CSS styles for standard search box with placeholder text-->
<style type="text/css">
    #tfheader{
        background-color:#c3dfef;
    }
    #tfnewsearch{
        float:right;
        padding:20px;
    }
    .tftextinput2{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
        color:#666;
        border:1px solid #0076a3; border-right:0px;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    }
    .tfbutton2 {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 7px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:bold;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        border: solid 1px #0076a3; border-right:0px;
        background: #0095cd;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00adee), to(#0078a5));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00adee,  #0078a5);
        border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    }
    .tfbutton2:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #007ead;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0095cc), to(#00678e));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0095cc,  #00678e);
    }
    /* Fixes submit button height problem in Firefox */
    .tfbutton2::-moz-focus-inner {
      border: 0;
    }
    .tfclear{
        clear:both;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- HTML for SEARCH BAR -->
    <div id="tfheader">
        <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="http://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-53200-19255-0/1?icep_ff3=9&pub=5575165347&toolid=10001&campid=5337851510&customid=&icep_uq=&icep_sellerId=&icep_ex_kw=&icep_sortBy=12&icep_catId=&icep_minPrice=&icep_maxPrice=&ipn=psmain&icep_vectorid=229466&kwid=902099&mtid=824&kw=lg">
                <input type="text" id="tfq2b" class="tftextinput2" name="q" size="21" maxlength="120" value="Search our website"><input type="submit" value="&gt;" class="tfbutton2">
        </form>
        <div class="tfclear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is a live one: [**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/fwjs0vcs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add all the other query parameters as hidden inputs like:

```
<body>
<!-- HTML for SEARCH BAR -->
<div id="tfheader">
       <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="http://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-53200-19255-0/1">
            <input type="text" id="tfq2b" class="tftextinput2" name="_nkw" size="21" maxlength="120" value="Search our website">
              <input type='hidden' name='icep_ff3' value='9'>
              <input type='hidden' name='pub' value='5575165347'>
              <input type='hidden' name='toolid' value='10001'>
              <input type='hidden' name='campid' value='5337851510'>
              <input type='hidden' name='icep_sortBy' value='12'>
              <input type='hidden' name='icep_vectorid' value='229466'>
              <input type='hidden' name='kwid' value='902099'>
              <input type='hidden' name='mtid' value='824'>
              <input type='hidden' name='kw' value='lg'>
            <input type="submit" value="&gt;" class="tfbutton2">

       </form>
       <div class="tfclear"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

etc.

this will build the URL you're looking for.

another option is to use javascript to redirect the user and parse his query yourself, something like:

```
var q = document.getElementById('tfq2b').value;
var formatQ = q.replace(/\s/g,'+');
window.location.href = 'http://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-53200-19255-0/1?icep_ff3=9&pub=5575165347&toolid=10001&campid=5337851510&customid=&icep_uq=&icep_sellerId=&icep_ex_kw=&icep_sortBy=12&icep_catId=&icep_minPrice=&icep_maxPrice=&ipn=psmain&icep_vectorid=229466&kwid=902099&mtid=824&kw=lg&q=' + formatQ;
```

I find it to be less 'clean' then the first option

EDIT

I just saw you also need to change the `name` of your textarea to `icep_uq` to get the link you've posted

Comment: Can you give me full solution?

Comment: I've updated my answer to try and help you a bit more - but you'll have to figure out the rest yourself, this isn't a coding service - if you want to hire me to do the work for you, you'll need to pay me ;-)

Comment: Your solution works and i want to mark it as an answer, but why i get dubble "samsung+galaxy+s5" in the address link?

Comment: sorry, had to deal with something - can you update the fiddle so I can see this issue?

Comment: tried it, the form sends me to: http://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-53200-19255-0/1?_nkw=galaxy+s+5&icep_ff3=9&pub=5575165347&toolid=10001&campid=5337851510&icep_sortBy=12&icep_vectorid=229466&kwid=902099&mtid=824&kw=lg and that translate into http://www.ebay.com/sch/items/?_nkw=&_sacat=&_ex_kw=&_mPrRngCbx=1&_udlo=&_udhi=&_sop=12&_fpos=&_fspt=1&_sadis=&LH_CAds=&_nkw=galaxy+s+5&rmvSB=true I don't see more than one `Samsung+galaxy+s5` - do you?

Comment: My bad, i mean dubble "_nkw=" in the address

Comment: true, the text input name should be `icep_uq` and not `_nkw` as I originally told you, change that and you're golden - Shana Tova buddy!

Comment: Works! Shana tova!